# Get values of effect options in vintageJS

Tags: imagefilter, vintagejs

I am working on website that add effects to images online using vintageJS. I have the following effect

```
   effect1 = {
        vignette: 0.7,
        viewFinder: "js/ImageEffects/assets/viewfinder/ttv-1.jpg",
        screen: { r: 227, g: 12, b: 169, a: 0.15 }
    };
```

and also I have the four basic effect of vintageJS( I get the four effects form the website of [vintageJS](http://vintagejs.com/) . The website should have nine effects which mean that I need another four effects. I try to write some random values but I didn't get a good effect. Can anyone give some values that produce a good effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the these effects:

```
    var RetroCurveR = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 52, 54, 55, 57, 59, 60, 62, 65, 67, 69, 70, 72, 74, 77, 79, 81, 83, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 97, 99, 101, 103, 107, 109, 111, 112, 116, 118, 120, 124, 126, 127, 129, 133, 135, 136, 140, 142, 143, 145, 149, 150, 152, 155, 157, 159, 162, 163, 165, 167, 170, 171, 173, 176, 177, 178, 180, 183, 184, 185, 188, 189, 190, 192, 194, 195, 196, 198, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 206, 207, 208, 209, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 218, 219, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 227, 228, 229, 229, 230, 231, 232, 232, 233, 234, 234, 235, 236, 236, 237, 238, 238, 239, 239, 240, 241, 241, 242, 242, 243, 244, 244, 245, 245, 245, 246, 247, 247, 248, 248, 249, 249, 249, 250, 251, 251, 252, 252, 252, 253, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255];
    var RetroCurveG = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 26, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43, 44, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 88, 89, 90, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 113, 114, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 122, 123, 124, 126, 127, 128, 129, 131, 132, 133, 135, 136, 137, 138, 140, 141, 142, 144, 145, 146, 148, 149, 150, 151, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 159, 160, 162, 163, 164, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 181, 182, 183, 184, 186, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 192, 193, 194, 195, 195, 196, 197, 199, 200, 201, 202, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 223, 224, 225, 226, 226, 227, 228, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 232, 232, 233, 234, 235, 235, 236, 236, 237, 238, 238, 239, 239, 240, 240, 241, 242, 242, 242, 243, 244, 245, 245, 246, 246, 247, 247, 248, 249, 249, 249, 250, 251, 251, 252, 252, 252, 253, 254, 255];
    var RetroCurveB = [53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 56, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 59, 59, 59, 60, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 63, 63, 63, 64, 65, 65, 65, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 69, 69, 70, 70, 71, 71, 72, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 75, 76, 77, 77, 78, 78, 79, 79, 80, 81, 81, 82, 82, 83, 83, 84, 85, 85, 86, 86, 87, 87, 88, 89, 89, 90, 90, 91, 91, 93, 93, 94, 94, 95, 95, 96, 97, 98, 98, 99, 99, 100, 101, 102, 102, 103, 104, 105, 105, 106, 106, 107, 108, 109, 109, 110, 111, 111, 112, 113, 114, 114, 115, 116, 117, 117, 118, 119, 119, 121, 121, 122, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 126, 127, 128, 129, 129, 130, 131, 132, 132, 133, 134, 134, 135, 136, 137, 137, 138, 139, 140, 140, 141, 142, 142, 143, 144, 145, 145, 146, 146, 148, 148, 149, 149, 150, 151, 152, 152, 153, 153, 154, 155, 156, 156, 157, 157, 158, 159, 160, 160, 161, 161, 162, 162, 163, 164, 164, 165, 165, 166, 166, 167, 168, 168, 169, 169, 170, 170, 171, 172, 172, 173, 173, 174, 174, 175, 176, 176, 177, 177, 177, 178, 178, 179, 180, 180, 181, 181, 181, 182, 182, 183, 184, 184, 184, 185, 185, 186, 186, 186, 187, 188, 188, 188, 189, 189, 189, 190, 190, 191, 191, 192, 192, 193, 193, 193, 194, 194, 194, 195, 196, 196, 196, 197, 197, 197, 198, 199];

    var EnhanceCurveR = [], EnhanceCurveG = [], EnhanceCurveB = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 255; ++i) 
        EnhanceCurveB[i] = EnhanceCurveG[i] = EnhanceCurveR[i] = Math.round(-12 * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 255) + i);

     effect1 = {
            noise: 20,
            vignette: 0.6,
            desaturate: 0.05,
            curves: { r: EnhanceCurveR, g: EnhanceCurveG, b: EnhanceCurveB },
            screen: { r: 12, g: 75, b: 153, a: 0.3 }
        };

 effect2 = {
        noise: 20,
        lighten: 0.1,
        vignette: 0.6,
        desaturate: 0.05,
        curves: { r: RetroCurveR, g: RetroCurveG, b: RetroCurveB },
        screen: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255, a: 0.25 }
    };

    effect3 = {
        sepia: true,
        lighten: 0.1,
        desaturate: 0.8,
        curves: { r: EnhanceCurveR, g: EnhanceCurveG, b: EnhanceCurveB },

    };
```